# where flask-login must be placed

Tags: python, flask, pip, flask-login

I want try to use `flask-login`, but have some issues with import. Maybe I put it in a wrong place?

So, I installed it with pip install `flask-login`, it was put in `python2.7/dist-packages`. And there I got the following:

```
python2.7/dist-packages
    - flask (python package)
    - flask-login.py
    - flask-login.pyc
    - Flask_Login-0.2.10.egg-info (folder)
    - flask-wtf (python package)
    - Flask_WTF-0.9.5.egg-info (folder)
    - Flask-0.10.1.egg-info
    - jinja2 (python package)
    - Jinja2-2.7.2.egg-info (folder) 
    and so on
```

So, as I can see from the content of dist-packages, all modules have python package and *egg-info folder. But flask-login does not have python package, only two .py files. And therefore I got Unresolved import `from flask.ext.login import LoginManager`.

In `flask` package I have `ext` package with **init**.py only in it.

If anyone knows what might went wrong I`ll really appreciate any help.

Btw, all modules (flask, jinja, wtforms) I`ve installed with pip.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for silly question. It appears I just should import like this: `from flask_login import LoginManager`. As it is just a module on libraries path.

But I have met a lot of imports like this  `from flask.ext.login import LoginManager`. Is there a way to put `login` inside `ext` and is it important?

Answer (score 1):

flask.ext has some magic lookup.

```
When a user does ``from flask.ext.login import foo`` it will attempt to
import ``from flask_login import foo`` first and when that fails it will
try to import ``from flaskext.login import foo``
```

So, do you have a flask_login, or a flaskext.login?

Comment: I just have **flask_login.py**

Comment: This is correct.  `from flask.ext.login import... ` Magically does the import from flask_login.py.  You can use either syntax.

Comment: Exactly, I tried that way, but it didn`t work. So I just use ***from flask_login import***